# getting a class having the same generic type of another class

Tags: java

This is my first question here, so thanks to everybody who make this forum lives.

I want my Image2D class to have the same generic type of my Point2D class.

Image2D.java :

```
 package utilities;

import ij.ImagePlus;
import utilities.Point2D;

public class Image2D<T> {

    ArrayList<Point2D<T>> original = new ArrayList<Point2D<T>>();

    public Image2D(ImagePlus imp) {
        // imp.getProcessor().getIntArray() returns a int[][]
        this.original = matrixToImage2D(imp.getProcessor().getIntArray());
    }

    private static <T> ArrayList<Point2D<T>> matrixToImage2D(T[][] matrix) {

        ArrayList<Point2D<T>> img = new ArrayList<Point2D<T>>();

        for (int row=0; row<matrix.length; row++) {
            for (int col=0; col<matrix[row].length; col++) {
                img.add(new Point2D(col, row, matrix[row][col]));
            }
        }

        return img;
    }

}
```

Point2D.java:

```
package utilities;

public class Point2D<T> {

    public int x;
    public int y;
    public T value;

    public Point2D(int col, int row, T value) {
        this.x = col;
        this.y = row;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return this.x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return this.y;
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

I must not use the good concept to do that, I just put the code to illustrate my idea.
Please can anyone tell me the java concepts I have to use ?

Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure I can follow? You define the generic type on instantiation, which means you have full control over the type used?
Otherwise you could always have the generic type extend another type in order to restrict the enduser in choice (e.g. <T extends List<?>> or <T extends MyInterface>)

Comment: The line `img.add(new Point2D(col, row, matrix[row][col]));` will produce an unchecked type warning. What you should be doing is providing a type parameter to your instantiation of `Point2D` like this: `img.add(new Point2D<T>(col, row, matrix[row][col]));`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you already know where the problem is - you've added a comment summarising it.

```
// imp.getProcessor().getIntArray() returns a int[][]
```

The `matrixToImage` method needs a `T[][]` but you are giving it an `int[][]` which will not work.

You must either make `ImagePlus` take a generic parameter (`ImagePlus<T>`) and then make `getIntArray` return a `T[][]` or you must make `matrixToImage2D` take an `int[][]` as a parameter.

One other alternative would be to use `T extends Number` and make adapter methods that translate between `int[][]` and `T[][]`.